# Any two events that are independent implies that the time between them are independent

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

> Theorem: By the Strong Markov Property, for a stopping time T and a Markov chain at state $X_{T_{n}} = y$, the state $X_{T_{n}+k}$ for $k\geqslant 0$ is independent of $X_{T_{n}}$ or $X_{T_{n}+k}$ is equivalent to the Markov chain with initial state $y$.

Clearly, the above theorem implies that any two or more states are independent to one another.

But how can I understand that the time between the occurrence of any two or more states are, thus, independent?